# Compare the count of data in same column in same table and display the larger value

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I wanted to a count of the same field for different values for example:

user{user_id, gender}

Gender can have obviously male or female :)

i want to get count for all the males and females i.e.

```
COUNT(male)   COUNT(female)  
   4               16
```

but i'm confused because they come from the same gender column thanks

ALSO, I Want the result to only display the higher count. Like

```
COUNT(female)
16
```

Comment: which SQL flavor are you using? MySQL, SQL server etc. please tag it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `case` statement.

```
select
    sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as total_male,
    sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as total_female
from user
```

If you are using MySQL then use following

```
select
    sum(gender = 'male') as total_male,
    sum(gender = 'female') as total_female
from user
```

If you are using PostgreSQL then use `filter`

```
select
    count(1) filter (where gender = 'male') as total_male,
    count(1) filter (where gender = 'female') as total_female
from user
```

You can achieve your final result by following query. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x93VV6pew5cD579cDPwXox/0).

```
select
    case 
        when total_male < total_female then total_female
        else total_male
    end as total_count
from
(
  select
    count(1) filter (where gender = 'male') as total_male,
    count(1) filter (where gender = 'female') as total_female
 from users
)  t
```

Comment: I need to display- if female count is greater than male then only display female else male

Comment: @Kim what if they both are equal?

Comment: @Kim added your expected answer. let me know if it works.